# Paperjs: only draw changed items

Tags: performance, paperjs

I'm working on a project where there are often thousands of items being drawn with paperjs. This is very slow as paperjs is redrawing every item even when they've not changed. Is there a way to avoid this?

I've found [this helpful paperjs fork](https://github.com/arthursw/paper.js#persistence) which does solve the problem, however it doesn't seem to be maintained anymore and there are some issues with it not clearing items correctly.

Just wondering if there is a 'proper' built in paperjs solution I've not found, or will I just need to make my own fork.

To create the items I'm using:

```
new Path.Rectangle(start, values.blockSize);
```

Then just changing it's colour later on.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86Lr5nLv/2/) so you can see how slow it gets at high grid sizes

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think my fork can help you. I should have provided the documentation. [Here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/paperjs/oTg73NhNUcM/EkY57pE2ZRAJ) is the thread where I explain what I changed and how it works (It should be possible to merge those changes with the latest paper.js).

And two examples: [persistance](https://oiio-arthursw.c9.io/drawings/spacePersistence.html) (progressive fade out) and [benchmark](https://oiio-arthursw.c9.io/drawings/index.html) (click and press space to see the difference). The code is [here](https://ide.c9.io/arthursw/oiio) in the drawings directory but I am not sure you can see it.

Comment: Thanks - I have already tried this and it almost there, just has issues with clearing items, plus being out of date. I may end up making my own fork from yours, to fix the bug and then use that

Comment: Yep, if you understand what I changed as I explain it in the thread that should work. Ask me if you need anything (I'm glad you find a use for this feature, I think it is an important one).

Comment: Thanks @arthur.sw.  Are you planning to submit your persistence changes to paper.js in a pull request?

Comment: The author does not really want to implement those features yet: "But I am weary to add fading effects since I want this library to be backend agnostic, so I can only add things that can easily be added in SVG / WebGL as well at a later point." 

Maybe we should re-ask if we show that many users are interested in it.

Comment: There are plans for an SVG backend in Paper.js but nothing is certain as of yet. Supposedly SVG takes care of those drawing optimisations where it updates only parts of the scene that have changed. I think the proper way of going about this is to see if we can modify Paper.js to update parts of the scene that have changed. I know it's a big task but that is the most proper solution here.

Comment: Has this in the mean time been resolved in paper.js ?